# equivalent metrics $\overline{d}(u,v)=\min\{d(u,v),1\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $\overline{d}(u,v)=\min\{d(u,v),1\}$. Then are $d$ and $\overline{d}$ topologically equivalent.

I have a specific question on the following 'proof' of this statement.

First it is shown, that $\overline{d}$ is indeed a metric. That is easy.
Then they show, that every $\overline{d}$-open set is $d$-open. That is easy, too.

When it is shown, that every $d$-open set is $\overline{d}$-open it goes as follows:

Let $U\subseteq X$ be $d$-open and $u\in U$. Then exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon^d(u)\subseteq\color{red}{X}$. Let $\delta=\min\{\varepsilon, \frac12\}\Rightarrow B_\delta^d(u)\subseteq\color{red}{X}$ and $B_\delta^d(u)\color{red}{=}B_\delta^\overline{d}(u)\Rightarrow$ U is $\overline{d}$-open.

I marked my problems red.
Why is it said, two times, that we have a subset of $X$, which is trivial. 
Should we not say, that we have subsets of $U$? I mean, it is not wrong, but it seems odd.

Also I do not see, why we have equality, which should also not be needed to state, that $U$ is $\overline{d}$-open. 
Is it not enough to show, that $B_\delta^d(u)\subseteq B_\delta^\overline{d}(u)$?

Am I mistaken?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's clearly a typo - the two red $X$$s should be $U$.

Comment: Thanks. What about the equality? I do not see why it holds. More specific, I do not see, why we have $B_\delta^\overline{d}(u)\subseteq B_\delta^d(u)$

Comment: Since $\delta < 1$, $d(u,x) < \delta$ if and only if $\overline d(u,x)<\delta$.

Comment: (If $\min(\alpha,1)<1$ then $\min(\alpha,1)=\alpha$)

Comment: Woops...${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich But do I need equality, in the first place?

Comment: Why ask questions that you know the answer to?

Comment: Because I am not used to seeing proofs, where there is said more then necessary, so I might be missing something. I do not think there is something wrong with that. Also I want to write the author an email, so he might clarify things, because I consider the given proof confusing, so I wanted to double check. Mea culpa.

Comment: I doubt there was any deep reason for writing the equality instead of just the inclusion that's needed -- since the equality is so obvious it may have just seemed silly to write $\subset$. If he _had_ written $\subset$ you'd be happier but I suspect many more people would wonder why he didn't say $=$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two red instances $X$ should indeed be $U$, the set we're trying to show openness of.

As we have $\delta=\min({\epsilon,\frac12})$ so $\delta \le \frac12 < 1$, we have $B^d_\delta(x)=B^{\bar d}_\delta(x)$: $y \in B^d_\delta(x)$ iff $d(x,y) < \delta$ iff $\bar{d}(x,y) (= \min(d(x,y),1)=d(x,y)) < \delta$ iff $y \in B^{\bar d}_\delta(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume U is d-open.
Prove U is the union of d-balls of radius less than 1.
Each of those d-balls is a $\bar d$-ball.
Thus U is a union of $\bar d$-balls, hence $\bar d$-open.